# Minimize number of non-zero elements in weights matrix Keras

Tags: python, keras

I would like to find the minimum number of embeddings with least number of non-zero elements to limit the number of non-zero weights in the Model.

My architecture now is:

```
def build_model(max_len, num_words, num_classes):
    I = layers.Input(shape=(max_len, ), name='Input')
    E = layers.Embedding(input_dim=num_words, 
                         output_dim=num_classes, 
                         embeddings_initializer='he_uniform',
                         name='Embeddings')(I)
    P = layers.GlobalAvgPool1D(name='Pool')(E)
    O = layers.Softmax(name='Softmax')(P)
    return models.Model(inputs=[I], outputs=[O])
```

the model looks like:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Input (InputLayer)           (None, 271)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
Embeddings (Embedding)       (None, 271, 26)           1358786   
_________________________________________________________________
Pool (GlobalAveragePooling1D (None, 26)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
Softmax (Softmax)            (None, 26)                0         
=================================================================
```

I am trying to zero out some weights after some iterations in order to only keep largest ones

```
model = build_model(MAX_LEN, NUM_TOKENS, NUM_CLASSES)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizers.Adam(lr=0.1), 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

total_params = NUM_TOKENS * NUM_CLASSES
need_params = 200
num_iterations = 16
decay = (total_params / need_params) ** (1 / num_iterations)

for i in range(num_iterations):
    wipe_out = int(total_params * (1 - 1 / decay ** (i + 1)))
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=512, epochs=i * 16, verbose=False)
    weights = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
    idx = np.argpartition(np.abs(weights), k, axis=None)
    weights.flat[idx[:wipe_out]] = 0
    model.layers[1].set_weights([weights])
```

but when training, model keeps updating this zero weights to non-zero values.
Is there a way to restrict updating zero values or some kind of a mask that will only allow changes to non-zero values (values-wise, not embeddings-row-wise)?

Could you please help me with embeddings or optimizer or regularizer to build a model with at most 200 non-zero elements in embedding matrix which will have relatively high accuracy?

The problem is: 
I have a list of "raw job titles" and "categorized job roles", I am trying to assign each word a distance to each of the categories to then avg them and pick a category with the highest weight. The main problem is to minimize number of non-zero elements in Embedding Matrix

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. It is possible to create a non-trainable binary mask variable `M` (the same size as your original weight matrix with 1s indicating those places that are allowed to update). You need to write a custom layer to support this feature. Note, this layer has two parameter matrices, one is the non-trainable `M` while the other is the trainable `W` and their elementwise product `W'=M*W` is the actual weight matrix in use.
2. Consider to use the `L1` regulation to encourage the sparsity in the weight matrix.

Update:

I share you a google colab notebook to demonstrate how to zero-out small weights during training. Because we do this for training, you will not see significant performance drops during testing. See details in this [notebook](https://github.com/rex-yue-wu/Notebooks/blob/master/forceSparseWeights.ipynb).

Note:

- the constraint I added is just a very simple version of option 1. This means you may see better performance if you write your layers with additional constraints.
- as the model sparsity increases, the model performance drops. And I believe this statement is true in general (i.e. it is very hard for your find a model with high sparsity and accuracy).

Comment: I've tried 2nd option, but that does not work. It assigns some huge weights to important values, but even though other values are close to 0 there a lot of them and they accumulate to some important amount. As I said, I've tried to zero them out every some operations, but the model still assigns some weights to them.

Comment: What you should do is to zero-out small weights during training. See my updated answer.